# HTML internal redirect after loading page

Tags: html, forms

Im new to HTML and i have this loader code i got from  : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_loader5

I adjust it to have a button and when i click on this button it sends an internal `GET` request to my code `/clients`.
I want the same code to work but without the button.

I want the loader to finish load and then redirect to the `/clients` page because now it is depended on the button click.
my code:

```
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()" style="margin:0;">
</body>
<div id="loader"></div>
<div style="display:none;" id="myDiv" class="animate-bottom">
<h2>Pres OK.</h2>
<form method="get" action="/clients">
    <button>OK</button>
</form>
</body>
</div>
```

simply removing the button line is not doing anything, just showing blank page and in my code i see
its not redirecting to `/clients`

how can i do this ?

EDIT:

**SOLVED** by changing myFunction like @Bert Maurau
suggested

```
<script>
var myVar;
function myFunction() {
  myVar = setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = '/clients' }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you basicly want to redirect the user if your "loading" is done?
I see you're calling the `myFunction()` on page load.

You could add a basic

`setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = '/clients' }, 1000);`

at the end of the function to redirect the user to /clients after one second.
(or when your loading function has done processing the data.

```
  myFunction() {

    // do stuff here
    // ...

    // wait for a second
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      // redirect to clients
      window.location.href = '/clients';
    }, 1000);

  }
```

Comment: I dont understand how to insert it , can you post more code ?  i have it now like that `<script>
var myVar;
function myFunction() {
  myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 3000);
}` what should i change here ?

Comment: @BatchenRegev I've added a sample for the myFunction code with the timeout because I'm not sure what `showPage` does at your end or if it's defined or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could submit your form from myFunction().

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("form_id").submit();
}
</script>
```

This function would be called when the page is finished loading and would submit the form without anybody pushing the button. You could even remove the button entirely.

Comment: what should i put in the `form_id` ? because as is it doesnt do anything

Comment: you need to give an id to your form with id="form_id" like you did with your div.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution:

```
</head>

<body onload="myFunction()" style="margin:0;">
```

> Remove the extra closing tag for BODY

```
<div id="loader"></div>
<div style="display:none;" id="myDiv" class="animate-bottom">
  <h2>Pres OK.</h2>
  <form method="get" action="/clients">
    <button>OK</button>
  </form>
  </body>
</div>
```

You can use the below Jquery Script

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      if($('#loader').hasClass('d-none') || $('#loader').css('display') == 'none'){ 
          // or any other check to ensure that the loader is finished.
          $('form').submit();
      }
   })
</script>
```

Please feel free to ask if you need more clarification.